# pyodbc results return empty if sql has a date condition

Tags: python, sql, pandas, datetime, pyodbc

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd


# Connection string
conx_string = "driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0}; server=; database=; UID=; PWD="

# Query to run
query = """
select new_name, CreatedOn, new_status, new_PaperApplicationSubmitted 
from new_application where createdon >= '01-Feb-2021'
and CreatedOn <= '1-Mar-2021'
and new_ApplicationType = 2 
and new_PaperApplicationSubmitted = 1
"""

# Creating connection and running the query
with pyodbc.connect(conx_string) as conx:
cursor = conx.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
query_data = cursor.fetchall()


# Define column names
query_columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]    


# dump records in dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=query_data, columns=query_columns)
# Print data type
print(df.dtypes)
print(df)

cursor.close()
conx.close()
```

I tried different variations of date and also tried to convert the date "where
createdon >= convert(datetime,'2021-05-01T00:00:00.000')
and CreatedOn <= convert(datetime,'2021-06-01T23:59:59.997')"

The SQL pulls results when I run in SQL server management studio

Comment: Does it return results without any clauses? Does your query work in SSMS when logged in as the User in your pyodbc connection string?

Comment: it does return results if I take the CreatedOn clause out

Comment: @PGHE Do you have any solution. Can you please help?

Comment: Got nothing sorry. If that exact query returns results without the 'createdon' clauses using pyodbc and no results with the clauses,  but the same query returns results with the 'createdon' clauses using another tool you've got an issue you need to raise with the developers.